# How to popup the confirm button?

Tags: javascript, php

I cannot figure out where to put my `onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure?')` due to lot of concatenation in my case so please help me guys. here is my code:

```
echo "<td><a href='" . base_url().'admin/play/delete/' .$row->id."onclick="."return confirm('Are you sure?')".'>" . "<img src='".base_url()."admin_css/images/delete.png' title='delete' "/></a>"/></a>"."<a href='".base_url().'admin/play/fav/' . $row->id . "'>" ."<img src='".base_url()."admin_css/images/star.png' title='edit'/>"."</a></td>";
```

Need help.

Comment: Break up your string concatenation in to separate/multiple commands and then it will be easier to debug.

Comment: start using templating engine, it will save a lot of time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple

```
   <td>
       <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/play/delete/<?php echo $row->id; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
       <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin_css/images/delete.png" title="delete"/>
       </a>
       <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/play/fav/<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin_css/images/star.png" title="edit"/>
        </a>
   </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please try this code**

```
echo '<td><a href="'.base_url().'admin/play/delete/'.$row->id.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')" ><img src="'.base_url().'admin_css/images/delete.png" title="delete" /></a><a href="'.base_url().'admin/play/fav/'.$row->id.'" ><img src="'.base_url().'admin_css/images/star.png" title="edit" /></a></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

i created it just to better understanding for you.
best luck.

```
echo '<td>';

echo '<a href="'.base_url().'admin/play/delete/'.$row->id.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')" >';
echo '<img src="'.base_url().'admin_css/images/delete.png" title="delete" />';
echo '</a>';

echo '<a href="'.base_url().'admin/play/fav/'.$row->id.'" >';
echo '<img src="'.base_url().'admin_css/images/star.png" title="edit" />';
echo '</a>';

echo '</td>';
```